# How can I fix this PHP Mail Form issue?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have a php contact form on my website. However when my customers input their e-mail address and submit their message I got a reply to my own e-mail. For example if they enter adam@yahoo.com I recieve the e-mail as myusername@myhostingprovider.com .... How can I fix this so the reply section shows the e-mail the customer input? Thank you.

Here is my code for my contact form

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post" class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="formValidationError bg-red-dark color-white" id="contactNameFieldError">
                                    <p class="center-text uppercase small-text">Name is required!</p>
                                </div>             
                                <div class="formValidationError bg-red-dark color-white" id="contactEmailFieldError">
                                    <p class="center-text uppercase small-text">Mail address required!</p>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="formValidationError bg-red-dark color-white" id="contactEmailFieldError2">
                                    <p class="center-text uppercase small-text">Mail address must be valid!</p>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="formValidationError bg-red-dark color-white" id="contactMessageTextareaError">
                                    <p class="center-text uppercase small-text">Message field is empty!</p>
                                </div>   
                                <div class="formFieldWrap">
                                    <label class="field-title contactNameField" for="contactNameField">Name:<span>(required)</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contactNameField" value="" class="contactField requiredField" id="contactNameField"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formFieldWrap">
                                    <label class="field-title contactEmailField" for="contactEmailField">Email: <span>(required)</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contactEmailField" value="" class="contactField requiredField requiredEmailField" id="contactEmailField"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formTextareaWrap">
                                    <label class="field-title contactMessageTextarea" for="contactMessageTextarea">Message: <span>(required)</span></label>
                                    <textarea name="contactMessageTextarea" class="contactTextarea requiredField" id="contactMessageTextarea"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formSubmitButtonErrorsWrap">
                                    <input type="submit" class="buttonWrap button button-grey contactSubmitButton" id="contactSubmitButton" value="SUBMIT" data-formId="contactForm"/>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Also here is the code for the PHP script

```
<?php
// variables start
$name = "";
$email = "";
$message = "";

$name =  trim($_POST['contactNameField']);
$email =  trim($_POST['contactEmailField']);
$message =  trim($_POST['contactMessageTextarea']);
// variables end

// email address starts
$emailAddress = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
// email address ends

$subject = "Mywebsite.com | Mobile - Message From: $name";  
$message = "<strong>From:</strong> $name <br/> <strong>E-Mail:</strong> $email </br><br/> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

$headers = 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

//send email function starts
mail($emailAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
//send email function ends
```

?>

Comment: have you tried replying and see where it went? your headers seem okay to me

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you haven't been adding to your header string, you've just been resetting it each time.
What you're finally sending to the mail function in the header variable is just;

'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"

What you need to do is either where you set $headers = , change the equals sign so it looks like this $headers .=

As that means that it will add on to the String. Or, just format it as one massive string.

```
<?php
$headers = 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

//send email function starts
mail($emailAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: When I do what you suggested the e-mail does not even come through into my inbox....any thing else you think could be wrong? When I take the period off ".=" and just use the = sign the e-mail arrives in my inbox

Comment: @user6505472 I think your headers are a little wrong. With the from header try just setting it as the email, remove the name variable and the <> symbols the php website explains how to do what you're doing http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php look at example 2